# Handling response object in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, wcf, asp-classic

I have a ASP.NET Web application and a Classic ASP Page which calls a WCF Service and gets a composite type R as response.

The ASP.NET Web application gets the composite object (R) and does the following:

```
if(R.IsValid)
{
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileName));
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", R.ByteArray.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(R.ByteArray);
                Response.End();
}
```

The Classic ASP Page gets the response too.

1. How do I cast it to the Composite type R(with IsValid and ByteArray)?
2. How do I do the operations that one can do the Response object in .NET with the ServerXMLHTTP object in javascript?

UPDATE:

```
function CallWcfAjax()
    {
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp");

       var url = "http://localhost:54329/DocumentGeneratorService.svc/ajaxEndpoint/";
        url = url + "GetDetailsMessageUsingPost";

      var xmlContents = loadXML("Data.xml");

       var getDetailsMessageUsingPostBody = '<GetDetailsMessageUsingPost><input>';
        getDetailsMessageUsingPostBody = getDetailsMessageUsingPostBody + xmlContents;
        getDetailsMessageUsingPostBody = getDetailsMessageUsingPostBody + '</input></GetDetailsMessageUsingPost>';

        // Send the HTTP request
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        xmlHttp.send(getDetailsMessageUsingPostBody);

        // Create result handler 
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= function X()
        {        
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                result.innerText = xmlHttp.responseText;
                // TODO: Handle xmlHttp.responseStream or other property
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't really cast in classic ASP, you should be able to call the methods without casting. Post your current classic ASP code and the error you get and we'll see.